# Can we configure an external FTP Location in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, file-storage, ftp

Can we configure an FTP Location which is outside Marketing Cloud FTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can configure an FTP Location which is outside Marketing Cloud FTP y following below steps.

1. Go to Administration
2. Navigate to Data Admnistration > File Location
3. Click Create
4. Select Location Type as "External FTP Site"
5. Enter external FTP details
6. Click Save

Screenshot below:
[image]